# EJS Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to understand what I'm skipping. It all seems correct to me but the code I'm trying to write is nested and a bit complicated so there's apparently something I don't know about EJS. `posts` has been passed over the EJS file from node.js. How to fix this code?

```
<%  for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
          let imageSrcs = [];
          for (let j = 0; j < posts[i].images.length; j++) {
            let imageSrc = "data:image/<%= posts[i].images[j].image.contentType %>;base64,\>
                        <% posts[i].images[j].image.data.toString('base64') %>";
            imageSrcs.push(imageSrc);
          }
    %>
        initializeSlider($(".slider-<%= i+1 %>"), <%= imageSrcs %>);
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use nested ejs tags. The way you have it at the moment, the first tag uses the first closing tag (the one after `.contentType`) to close and thus there is an extra closing tag left, since the second opening tag is being ignored.

Changing your code to the following should fix your problem.

```
<%  for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    let imageSrcs = [];
    
    for (let j = 0; j < posts[i].images.length; j++) {
        let imageSrc = `data:image/${posts[i].images[j].image.contentType};base64,\>
            ${posts[i].images[j].image.data.toString('base64')}`;
        imageSrcs.push(imageSrc);
    }%>
    
    initializeSlider($(".slider-<%= i+1 %>"), <%= imageSrcs %>);
    
<% } %>
```